# Hiding Window Titlebars (like the hiding the taskbar)

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

Users can configure the Windows taskbar to slide out of view (hidden) and can explicitly motion (summon) for the taskbar when needed.

**Is there an example of similar capability with the titlebar of a window?**

It occupies valuable real-estate and (in my view) not the best use of space.

Comment: Not inbuilt; you'll need a 3rd party utility.

Comment: Intriguing...  What is the name of such a utility?